# Making a game but stuck on calling functions

Tags: python

I am making a text based game where a player moves around from room to room. Each room is a Class with 4 positions in each room. I am using a Function for each position and Functions to take an input on where in the room to go. The problem is I want to Call a position Function then have that Function call an input Function again but because my Functions are all defined above the input Functions it doesn't work

Here is the code from the Class. The input Functions are at the bottom.

class Room2:

```
room = 2

firstAid_location = []

if firstAid_room == room:
    firstAid_location = firstAid_spawn


def starting_position(self):

    global room2_minion
    global playerHealth
    global firstAid_room

    position_start = 1
    minion_hit = random.randrange(1, 3)

    print('You Are Now In The North Room')

    if position_start == self.firstAid_location:

        print('You Found The First Aid Kit')
        print('Your Health Has Been Increased By 2HP!')
        playerHealth += 2
        firstAid_room += 10

        if position_start == room2_minion:
            print('A Minion Has Attacked!')

            if minion_hit == 1:
                print('The Minion Hit You And Then Fainted From Exhaustion')
                print('You Have Lost 2HP')
                playerHealth -= 2
                room2_minion += 10

                if playerHealth <= 0:
                    print('You Have Died')
                    quit()

                else:
                    print('You Have', playerHealth, 'HP Left')


            else:
                print('The Minion Missed The Attack!')
                room2_minion += 10


    elif position_start == room2_minion:
        print('A Minion Has Attacked!')

        if minion_hit == 1:
            print('The Minion Hit You Then Fainted From Exhaustion')
            print('You Have Lost 2HP')
            playerHealth -= 2
            room2_minion += 10

            if playerHealth <= 0:
                print('You Have Died')
                quit()

            else:
                print('You Have', playerHealth, 'HP Left')


        else:
            print('The Minion Missed The Attack!')


    else:
        pass


def pos1(self):

    global room2_minion
    global playerHealth
    global firstAid_room

    position1 = 1
    minion_hit = random.randrange(1, 3)

    if position1 == self.firstAid_location:

        print('You Found The First Aid Kit')
        print('Your Health Has Been Increased By 2HP!')
        playerHealth += 2
        firstAid_room += 10

        if position1 == room2_minion:
            print('A Minion Has Attacked!')

            if minion_hit == 1:
                print('The Minion Hit You And Then Fainted From Exhaustion')
                print('You Have Lost 2HP')
                playerHealth -= 2
                room2_minion += 10

                if playerHealth <= 0:
                    print('You Have Died')
                    quit()

                else:
                    print('You Have', playerHealth, 'HP Left')

            else:
                print('The Minion Missed The Attack!')
                room2_minion += 10

    elif position1 == room2_minion:
        print('A Minion Has Attacked!')

        if minion_hit == 1:
            print('The Minion Hit You Then Fainted From Exhaustion')
            print('You Have Lost 2HP')
            playerHealth -= 2
            room2_minion += 10

            if playerHealth <= 0:
                print('You Have Died')
                quit()

            else:
                print('You Have', playerHealth, 'HP Left')

        else:
            print('The Minion Missed The Attack!')

    else:
        pass


def pos2(self):

    global room2_minion
    global playerHealth
    global firstAid_room

    position2 = 2
    minion_hit = random.randrange(1, 3)

    if position2 == self.firstAid_location:

        print('You Found The First Aid Kit')
        print('Your Health Has Been Increased By 2HP!')
        playerHealth += 2
        firstAid_room += 10

        if position2 == room2_minion:
            print('A Minion Has Attacked!')

            if minion_hit == 1:
                print('The Minion Hit You And Then Fainted From Exhaustion')
                print('You Have Lost 2HP')
                playerHealth -= 2
                room2_minion += 10

                if playerHealth <= 0:
                    print('You Have Died')
                    quit()

                else:
                    print('You Have', playerHealth, 'HP Left')

            else:
                print('The Minion Missed The Attack!')
                room2_minion += 10

    elif position2 == room2_minion:
        print('A Minion Has Attacked!')

        if minion_hit == 1:
            print('The Minion Hit You Then Fainted From Exhaustion')
            print('You Have Lost 2HP')
            playerHealth -= 2
            room2_minion += 10

            if playerHealth <= 0:
                print('You Have Died')
                quit()

            else:
                print('You Have', playerHealth, 'HP Left')

        else:
            print('The Minion Missed The Attack!')

    else:
        pass




def pos3(self):

    global room2_minion
    global playerHealth
    global firstAid_room

    position3 = 3
    minion_hit = random.randrange(1, 3)

    if position3 == self.firstAid_location:

        print('You Found The First Aid Kit')
        print('Your Health Has Been Increased By 2HP!')
        playerHealth += 2
        firstAid_room += 10

        if position3 == room2_minion:
            print('A Minion Has Attacked!')

            if minion_hit == 1:
                print('The Minion Hit You And Then Fainted From Exhaustion')
                print('You Have Lost 2HP')
                playerHealth -= 2
                room2_minion += 10

                if playerHealth <= 0:
                    print('You Have Died')
                    quit()

                else:
                    print('You Have', playerHealth, 'HP Left')

            else:
                print('The Minion Missed The Attack!')
                room2_minion += 10

    elif position3 == room2_minion:
        print('A Minion Has Attacked!')

        if minion_hit == 1:
            print('The Minion Hit You Then Fainted From Exhaustion')
            print('You Have Lost 2HP')
            playerHealth -= 2
            room2_minion += 10

            if playerHealth <= 0:
                print('You Have Died')
                quit()

            else:
                print('You Have', playerHealth, 'HP Left')

        else:
            print('The Minion Missed The Attack!')

    else:
        pass


def pos4(self):

    global room2_minion
    global playerHealth
    global firstAid_room

    position4 = 4
    minion_hit = random.randrange(1, 3)

    if position4 == self.firstAid_location:

        print('You Found The First Aid Kit')
        print('Your Health Has Been Increased By 2HP!')
        playerHealth += 2
        firstAid_room += 10

        if position4 == room2_minion:
            print('A Minion Has Attacked!')

            if minion_hit == 1:
                print('The Minion Hit You And Then Fainted From Exhaustion')
                print('You Have Lost 2HP')
                playerHealth -= 2
                room2_minion += 10

                if playerHealth <= 0:
                    print('You Have Died')
                    quit()

                else:
                    print('You Have', playerHealth, 'HP Left')

            else:
                print('The Minion Missed The Attack!')
                room2_minion += 10

    elif position4 == room2_minion:
        print('A Minion Has Attacked!')

        if minion_hit == 1:
            print('The Minion Hit You Then Fainted From Exhaustion')
            print('You Have Lost 2HP')
            playerHealth -= 2
            room2_minion += 10

            if playerHealth <= 0:
                print('You Have Died')
                quit()

            else:
                print('You Have', playerHealth, 'HP Left')

        else:
            print('The Minion Missed The Attack!')

    else:
        pass


def pos1_input(self):
    pass

def pos2_input(self):
    pass

def pos3_input(self):
    pass

def pos4_input(self):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Representing rooms as functions is unlikely to be a viable approach. As you've discovered, you end up repeating a lot of code.

This sort of application is a classic use case for [Python objects and classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). (It looks as though you may still be learning Python, so you may not have encountered these yet.) Modelling rooms, minions, and items each as a class will allow you to express your game in a much simpler and more straightforward way.

Comment: Well yes I've only been learning Python for about a month. I'm representing the rooms as Classes not sure if that's what you meant.  Also you didn't solve the problem. I'm not re-writing everything from scratch because I'm 80% of the way done.

Comment: @C_Isn't_Sharp Well… you didn't actually ask a question up front, so I assumed what you were trying to ask was "what am I doing wrong here". I do see that these functions are wrapped in a class, but that doesn't mean that you're using classes in an effective, useful way -- and that will need to change.

Comment: Ok but how do I go about addressing the problem of calling a Function if it is defined below the Function I'm calling it from and cannot be defined above it. I posted the question looking for a solution to the specific problem. I structured the code in a way that makes sense to me based on my goals for the game, you may tackle it differently but the most effective way for me is dividing my code up into a Class for each room. Thanks anyway